# Getting fatal error on sending multiple requests with Guzzle?

Tags: php, guzzle

This is the error I get

```
Argument 1 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::send() must implement interface GuzzleHttp\Message\RequestInterface, array given,
```

and this is the code I am using

```
$guzzleResponses = $client->send(array(
$client->get('http://www.sitepoint.com/'),
$client->get('http://www.sitepoint.com/'),
$client->get('http://www.sitepoint.com/')
));

foreach($guzzleResponses as $guzzleResponse) {
$goutteObject = new Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Response(
       $guzzleResponse->getBody(true), 
       $guzzleResponse->getStatusCode(), 
       $guzzleResponse->getHeaders()
);
}
```

I understand the error means I am passing an array when it expected something else. But I want to process multiple requests simultaneously and unable ot think any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was already asked (by yourself) and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454946/sending-multiple-goutte-requests-asynchronously).  To send multiple requests asynchronously you must use [GuzzleHttp\Pool](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clients.html#sending-requests-with-a-pool)

Your call to `GuzzleHttp\Client->send()` is incorrect.  You are actually feeding it an array of ResponseInterfaces (not what is intended).
The `GuzzleHttp\Client->get()` will internally call `$this->sent($this->createRequest('GET', $url, $options))`which means that it will actually perform the http request and return an instance of `GuzzleHttp\Message\ResponseInterface`.

Answer (score 1):

As per several other questions with the same need an answer with the new Guzzlehttp package **guzzlehttp/guzzle** is available at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649888/how-to-match-a-result-to-a-request-when-sending-multiple-requests/32751032#32751032) . Follow the link for a full description or look at the example below

See example *here*

```
    $newClient = new  \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => $base]);
    foreach($documents->documents as $doc){

        $params = [
            'language' =>'eng',
            'text' => $doc->summary,
            'apikey' => $key
        ];

        $requestArr[$doc->reference] = $newClient->getAsync( '/1/api/sync/analyze/v1?' . http_build_query( $params) );
    }

    $responses = \GuzzleHttp\Promise\unwrap($requestArr); //$newClient->send( $requestArr );
```